# Локализация не работает на первом Activity

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences, locale

Написал код локализации через настройки. 
В настройках я меняю язык на другой и он меняется по все приложении но только выхожу и захожу заново язык на первом `Activity` меняется на язык по умолчанию на всех остальных язык который установлен в настройках.
Вот моя архитектура приложение 
`SplachActivity >>> Main >>>` и много других `Activity` в которых все работает.
Вот код `BaseActivity`

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LocalizationDelegate localizationDelegate = new LocalizationDelegate(this);
    private String activeLangCode = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        localizationDelegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        activeLangCode = (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext())).getString(getString(R.string.pref_general_language),"uk");

        setLanguage(activeLangCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        localizationDelegate.onResume();
    }

    public final void setLanguage(String language) {
        localizationDelegate.setLanguage(language);
    }

    public final void setLanguage(Locale locale) {
        localizationDelegate.setLanguage(locale);
    }

    public final void setDefaultLanguage(String language) {
        localizationDelegate.setDefaultLanguage(language);
    }

    public final void setDefaultLanguage(Locale locale) {
        localizationDelegate.setDefaultLanguage(locale);
    }

    public final String getLanguage() {
        return localizationDelegate.getLanguage();
    }

    public final Locale getLocale() {
        return localizationDelegate.getLocale();
    }

}
```

Интересен вот ещё какой факт если свернуть приложение и запустить снова тогда язык в Main появляется. Какой метод из жизненного цикла Activity я забыл прописать? 
Код проблемной  Main :

```
public class Main extends BaseActivity implements DialogUtilities.OnCompleteListener, BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler{

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;
    private RelativeLayout mNotificationView;
    CheckSubscribe checks;
    BillingProcessor bp;
    private ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> background = new ArrayList<>();
    private int icon [] = {R.drawable.anamnez,R.drawable.analysis,R.drawable.farmacopea,R.drawable.library,R.drawable.quiz,R.drawable.develop};
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        AdsUtilities.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).showBannerAd((AdView) findViewById(R.id.adsView));
        AppUpdateChecker appUpdateChecker=new AppUpdateChecker(this);
        appUpdateChecker.checkForUpdate(false);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        activity = Main.this;
        context = getApplicationContext();
        mNotificationView =  findViewById(R.id.notificationView);
        checks = new CheckSubscribe();
        checks.execute();
        DrawerUtil.getDrawer(this, toolbar);
        initMain();
    }
    private void initMain(){
        title.add(getString(R.string.blank));
        background.add("https://khmelnytsky.com.ua/sites/default/files/styles/wide_background/public/images/news/2018/08/241665.jpg?itok=-A-QogDS");
        title.add(getString(R.string.analysis));
        background.add("https://ukr.media/static/ba/aimg/3/6/8/368068_1.jpg");
        title.add(getString(R.string.pharmacy));
        background.add("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/Generic_finasteride_tablets_cipla.jpg/1200px-Generic_finasteride_tablets_cipla.jpg");
        title.add(getString(R.string.library));
        background.add("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Duke_Humfrey%27s_Library_Interior_6%2C_Bodleian_Library%2C_Oxford%2C_UK_-_Diliff.jpg");
        title.add(getString(R.string.quiz));
        background.add("https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5SR6WoKVFUo/WoRyZedumPI/AAAAAAAAAPw/iwp9gG4AjhU5jM3QrI9XBngiJwSKPBo8QCLcBGAs/s1600/%25D0%25BA%25D1%2580%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BA%2B3%25D0%25B0.jpg");
        title.add(getString(R.string.under_dev));
        background.add("https://www.rbc.ua/static/img/s/e/security_for_developers_650x410.jpg");

        initRecyclerView();
    }


    private void initRecyclerView(){
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RecycleViewAdapterMain adapter = new RecycleViewAdapterMain(this, background,icon,title);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
    }
    @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
    @Override
   public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
    }
    @Override
   public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
        if (bp.isSubscribed(SUBSCRIPTION_ID())) {
            setIsSubscribe(true, getApplicationContext());
        } else {
            setIsSubscribe(false, getApplicationContext());
        }
    }
   private String SUBSCRIPTION_ID(){
        return getResources().getString(R.string.subscription_id);
    }
   public void setIsSubscribe(boolean purchased, Context c){
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor= prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(AppConstants.PRODUCT_ID_SUBSCRIBE, purchased);
        editor.apply();
    }
    @Override
   public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
    }
    @Override
   public void onBillingInitialized() {
    }
    @Override
   public void onComplete(Boolean isOkPressed, String viewIdText) {
        if (isOkPressed) {
            if (viewIdText.equals(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY_EXIT_OPTION)) {
                activity.finishAffinity();
            }
        }
    }
   private class CheckSubscribe extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String license = getResources().getString(R.string.google_play_license);
            bp = new BillingProcessor(context, license, Main.this);
            bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Код локализации:

```
public abstract class AppCompatPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDelegate().installViewFactory();
        getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getDelegate().onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
        return getDelegate().getSupportActionBar();
    }
    public void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar) {
        getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
        return getDelegate().getMenuInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void addContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        getDelegate().addContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        getDelegate().onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTitleChanged(CharSequence title, int color) {
        super.onTitleChanged(title, color);
        getDelegate().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        getDelegate().onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getDelegate().onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getDelegate().onDestroy();
    }

    public void invalidateOptionsMenu() {
        getDelegate().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate() {
        if (mDelegate == null) {
            mDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
        }
        return mDelegate;
    }
}
```

и еще:

```
public class BasePreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    private LocalizationDelegate localizationDelegate = new LocalizationDelegate(this);
    private String activeLangCode = "";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        localizationDelegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadActiveLangCode();
    }
    public void loadActiveLangCode() {
        activeLangCode = (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext())).getString(getString(R.string.pref_general_language),"uk");
        setLanguage(activeLangCode);
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        localizationDelegate.onResume();
    }
    public final void setLanguage(String language) {
        localizationDelegate.setLanguage(language);
    }
    public final void setLanguage(Locale locale) {
        localizationDelegate.setLanguage(locale);
    }
    public final void setDefaultLanguage(String language) {
        localizationDelegate.setDefaultLanguage(language);
    }
    public final void setDefaultLanguage(Locale locale) {
        localizationDelegate.setDefaultLanguage(locale);
    }
    public final String getLanguage() {
        return localizationDelegate.getLanguage();
    }
    public final Locale getLocale() {
        return localizationDelegate.getLocale();
    }
}
```

и код активити настроек:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends BasePreferenceActivity {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private ListPreference language;
    private boolean isCreating = true;
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AppBarLayout bar;
        mActivity = this;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
            bar = (AppBarLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.locale, root, false);
            root.addView(bar, 0);
        } else {
            ViewGroup root = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            ListView content = (ListView) root.getChildAt(0);
            root.removeAllViews();
            bar = (AppBarLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.locale, root, false);
            int height;
            TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
            if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
                height = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }else{
                height = bar.getHeight();
            }
            content.setPadding(0, height, 0, 0);
            root.addView(content);
            root.addView(bar);
        }
        Toolbar tbar = (Toolbar) bar.getChildAt(0);
        DrawerUtil.getDrawer(this,tbar);
        tbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        setupSimplePreferencesScreen();
        isCreating = false;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void setupSimplePreferencesScreen() {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        language = (ListPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_general_language));
        setPreferenceSummary(language, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(language.getContext()).getString(language.getKey(), ""));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(language);
    }
    private Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            String stringValue = value.toString();
            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
                preference.setSummary(
                        index >= 0
                                ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                                : null);
            } else {
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }
            if(!isCreating) {
                setLanguage(stringValue);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }
    private static void setPreferenceSummary(Preference preference, String value) {
        preference.setSummary(value);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        final View result = super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            // If we're running pre-L, we need to 'inject' our tint aware Views in place of the
            // standard framework versions
            switch (name) {
                case "EditText":
                    return new AppCompatEditText(this, attrs);
                case "Spinner":
                    return new AppCompatSpinner(this, attrs);
                case "CheckBox":
                    return new AppCompatCheckBox(this, attrs);
                case "RadioButton":
                    return new AppCompatRadioButton(this, attrs);
                case "CheckedTextView":
                    return new AppCompatCheckedTextView(this, attrs);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) {
        super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
        if (preference!=null) {
            if (preference instanceof PreferenceScreen) {
                if (((PreferenceScreen) preference).getDialog() != null) {
                    ((PreferenceScreen) preference).getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundDrawable(this.getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable());
                    setUpNestedScreen((PreferenceScreen) preference);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void setUpNestedScreen(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen) {
        final Dialog dialog = preferenceScreen.getDialog();
        AppBarLayout appBar;
        View listRoot = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ViewGroup mRootView = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent();
            appBar = (AppBarLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.locale, root, false);
            root.addView(appBar, 0);
        } else {
            ListView content = (ListView) mRootView.getChildAt(0);
            mRootView.removeAllViews();
            LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(this);
            LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams LLParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            LL.setLayoutParams(LLParams);
            appBar = (AppBarLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.locale, mRootView, false);
            LL.addView(appBar);
            LL.addView(content);
            mRootView.addView(LL);
        }

        if(listRoot != null){
            listRoot.setPadding(0, listRoot.getPaddingTop(), 0, listRoot.getPaddingBottom());
        }
        Toolbar Tbar = (Toolbar) appBar.getChildAt(0);
        Tbar.setTitle(preferenceScreen.getTitle());
        Tbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    public void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Вот [видео](https://youtu.be/pxu5q3NjQNg) что бы понятнее было в чем проблема... извините ещё не полностью перевел приложение на другие языки

**КОД ДЕЛЕГАТА**

```
public class LocalizationDelegate {

    private static final String KEY_ACTIVITY_LOCALE_CHANGED = "activity_locale_changed";

    // Boolean flag to check that activity was recreated from locale changed.
    private boolean isLocalizationChanged = false;

    // Prepare default language.
    private String currentLanguage = LanguageSetting.getDefaultLanguage();

    private final Activity activity;
    private final List<OnLocaleChangedListener> localeChangedListeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public LocalizationDelegate(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void addOnLocaleChangedListener(OnLocaleChangedListener onLocaleChangedListener) {
        localeChangedListeners.add(onLocaleChangedListener);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setupLanguage();
        checkBeforeLocaleChanging();
    }

    // Provide method to set application language by country name.
    public final void setLanguage(String language) {
        if (!isCurrentLanguageSetting(language)) {
            LanguageSetting.setLanguage(activity, language);
            notifyLanguageChanged();
        }
    }

    // Provide method to set application language by locale.
    public final void setLanguage(Locale locale) {
        setLanguage(locale.getLanguage());
    }

    public final void setDefaultLanguage(String language) {
        LanguageSetting.setDefaultLanguage(language);
    }

    public final void setDefaultLanguage(Locale locale) {
        LanguageSetting.setDefaultLanguage(locale.getLanguage());
    }

    // Get current language
    public final String getLanguage() {
        return LanguageSetting.getLanguage();
    }

    // Get current locale
    public final Locale getLocale() {
        return LanguageSetting.getLocale(activity);
    }

    // Check that bundle come from locale change.
    // If yes, bundle will obe remove and set boolean flag to "true".
    private void checkBeforeLocaleChanging() {
        boolean isLocalizationChanged = activity.getIntent().getBooleanExtra(KEY_ACTIVITY_LOCALE_CHANGED, false);
        if (isLocalizationChanged) {
            this.isLocalizationChanged = true;
            activity.getIntent().removeExtra(KEY_ACTIVITY_LOCALE_CHANGED);
        }
    }

    // Setup language to locale and language preference.
    // This method will called before onCreate.
    private void setupLanguage() {
        Locale locale = LanguageSetting.getLocale(activity);
        setupLocale(locale);
        currentLanguage = locale.getLanguage();
        LanguageSetting.setLanguage(activity, locale.getLanguage());
    }

    // Set locale configuration.
    private void setupLocale(Locale locale) {
        updateLocaleConfiguration(activity, locale);
    }

    private void updateLocaleConfiguration(Context context, Locale locale) {
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        config.locale = locale;
        DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, dm);
    }

    // Avoid duplicated setup
    private boolean isCurrentLanguageSetting(String language) {
        return language.equals(LanguageSetting.getLanguage());
    }

    // Let's take it change! (Using recreate method that available on API 11 or more.
    private void notifyLanguageChanged() {
        sendOnBeforeLocaleChangedEvent();
        activity.getIntent().putExtra(KEY_ACTIVITY_LOCALE_CHANGED, true);
        callDummyActivity();
        activity.recreate();
    }

    // If activity is run to backstack. So we have to check if this activity is resume working.
    public void onResume() {
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                checkLocaleChange();
                checkAfterLocaleChanging();
            }
        });
    }

    // Check if locale has change while this activity was run to backstack.
    private void checkLocaleChange() {
        if (!isCurrentLanguageSetting(currentLanguage)) {
            sendOnBeforeLocaleChangedEvent();
            isLocalizationChanged = true;
            callDummyActivity();
            activity.recreate();
        }
    }

    // Call override method if local is really changed
    private void checkAfterLocaleChanging() {
        if (isLocalizationChanged) {
            sendOnAfterLocaleChangedEvent();
            isLocalizationChanged = false;
        }
    }

    private void sendOnBeforeLocaleChangedEvent() {
        for (OnLocaleChangedListener changedListener : localeChangedListeners) {
            changedListener.onBeforeLocaleChanged();
        }
    }

    private void sendOnAfterLocaleChangedEvent() {
        for (OnLocaleChangedListener listener : localeChangedListeners) {
            listener.onAfterLocaleChanged();
        }
    }

    private void callDummyActivity() {
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, BlankDummyActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте устанавливать язык до вызова `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб к сожалению  это роли не играет.

Comment: Попробуйте описать ещё раз в какой именно момент у вас что-то идёт не так. Насколько я понял у вас на какой-то конкретной активити всегда не работает? Или при возврате на какую-то определённую активити? Или при старте приложения? Этот момент не очень понятен. Возможно, если у вас второй случай, вам надо просто `onRestart()` переопределить и там ещё раз язык установить в случае необходимости и перезапустить активити.

Comment: Смотрите стартует  у меня приложение сначала идет SplashActivity потом Main вот на Activity Main локализация не работает при переходе на другие активити с Main локализация работает. После того как закрыл я приложение и снова открыл то на Main появляется заданная локализация. Не могу пофиксить этот баг.

Comment: И при этом все активити унаследованы от BaseActivity? И на SplashActivity всё работает? Тогда, видимо, проблема в коде MainActivity. Попробуйте её на рустую активити заменить - будет ли работать? Ну и покажите в вопросе код смены языка и код проблеммной активити

Comment: SplashActivity у меня не имеет текста что бы локазироватся, и да все активити унаследую BaseActivity.

Comment: Ох, много кода... Сложно понять что не так. Попробуйте таки в onRecreate проверять язык и менять если надо. Это исправит проблему с неактивацией языка при возврате на MainActivivity после активити настроек. И не забудьте пересоздать активити при этом.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб♦ Вот [видео](https://youtu.be/pxu5q3NjQNg) что бы понятнее было в чем проблема... извините ещё не полностью перевел приложение на другие языки

Comment: Я ещё больше запутался) У вас в видео сначала приложение на украинском языке, потом безо всякого перехода (может я что-то не заметил) оно становится частично на английском... Наверное, нужны детали того как переключается язык. У вас некий делагат за жто отвечает, но его кода нет. В нём у вас активити пересоздаётся? Заранее, чтобы не было недоразумений - не факт, что я сумею как-то помочь, но код делагата, быть может, пригодится тому, кто вам помочь сможет. Ну и надо как-то в вопросе таки привести однозначную картину происходящего, мне лично она всё ещё не ясна.

Comment: Как я и написал выше я не полностью перевел приложение на другие языки. По умолчанию приложение имеет украинский язык. Вот я и пишу что в других активностях которые идут после Main язык меняется. Делегат это имплементированая библитека `com.akexorcist:localizationactivity:1.1.2` Сейчас напишу код делегата в вопросе

Comment: Но я не увидел в видео, что вы в принципе меняете язык. Пересозданий активити также не видно. Из этого я делаю вывод, что язык на видео вы не меняли. Следовательно, вы его сменили перед началом видео? В другой активити? И после этого вернулись на главную активити и там язык не сменён? Если да, то как я и отмечал выше дважды (вроде) - вам надо `onRestart()` переопределить и там проверять язык и менять и пересоздавать активити если нужно сменить язык.

Comment: Вот полное [видео](https://youtu.be/iNlaHVnEFBM) и [приложение](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l6MzE6nW7CrsNFLWUFMVEvNWYNblLqqD/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Видео посмотрел. Если у вас каждый экран - активити, а не фрагменты тоже, то проблема, кажется, не только в одном активити. Файлы от незнакомых людей в интернете не качаю - смотреть у себя не буду. Судя по коду делагата вы явно делаете лишние вещи. Не нужно завязывать смену языка на параметры, передаваемые в Intent - это явно лишнее. Также лишнее - некая `DummyActivity`. Работать должно так: 1. Меняем язык, записывая в префы что-то. 2. В активити в `onCreate` устанавливаем язык через конфиг.  3. Так при пересоздании активити язык будет меняться. 4. На предыдущих активити, надо onRecreate юзать

Comment: Да вы правы. У меня каждый экран это отдельная активити я так и не научился пользоваться фрагментами. Эту локализацию я использовал по причине она очень легка в реализации. Локализацию взял от сюда https://github.com/barisatalay/AndroidLocalizationExample

Comment: Не, эта локализация наоборот излишне усложнена) Я бы дал вам свою либу, которая тоже самое делает, но она 3 года назад была написана и у меня всё не доходят руки её причесать и куда-то выложить. Однако там всё работало по описанному выше принципу и все сценарии обрабатывались корректно. Попробуйте без делегата вручную сменить язык в onCreate и onRecreate. И вручную же, без делагата пересоздавать активити. И ориентриоваться при этом на префы, а не на данные в интенте, т.к. там могут быть старые данные, из-за которых у вас и проблема.

Comment: Спасибо если перепишете свою локализацию скиньте пожалуйста а я пока буду искать проблемы в этой. Извините за беспокойство, зря на меня потратили уйму времени.

Comment: Посмотрите вот эту статью - там, вроде, нормально всё расписано: https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758. Не советую пытаться вашу текущую реализацию до ума доводить. Она излишне усложенена. Лучше попробовать вручную своё написать. ОК, скину, но это может быть и не в этом году)

Comment: И явно не стоит использовать заброшенные проекты с нулём звёзд. Там редко что-то рабочее можно найти)